# tox: how to specify python micro version

Tags: python, tox

In the example below, the python version is 2.7.6.

- Why is it 2.7.6, and not the latest 2.7.15?
- How do I specify 2.7.15?

Set up

```
$ tox --version
2.7.0 imported from /home/obk/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tox/__init__.py

$ ls
tox.ini

$ cat tox.ini
[tox]
envlist = py27
skipsdist = True

[testenv]
commands = python -V
```

Running it:

```
$ tox -r
py27 recreate: /home/obk/repos/test/.tox/py27
py27 installed:
py27 runtests: PYTHONHASHSEED='4191112007'
py27 runtests: commands[0] | python -V
Python 2.7.6
___________________________________ summary ___________________________________________
  py27: commands succeeded
  congratulations :)
```

The reason why I want the latest 2.7.15 is because my project has a dependency (`my_foo` -> `nbconvert` -> `tornado`) that is now using `ssl.create_default_context` which was [added in 2.7.9](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#ssl.create_default_context).

Answer (score 4):

> Why is it 2.7.6, and not the latest 2.7.15?

Because the version of Python 2.7 on your computer is 2.7.6.

> How do I specify 2.7.15?

Specify `basepython = /path/to/python2.7.15` under `[testenv]`, where `/path/to/python2.7.15` is a path to a local copy of exactly version 2.7.15.

Comment: I installed python 2.7.15 via conda and listed `basepython=/full/path/to/anaconda/py2715/python` as you suggested. This led to an error (which changes depending on what env I have activated etc), but in all cases the error message has a line `New python executable in /home/obk/repos/test/.tox/py27/bin/python`, and doing `/home/obk/repos/test/.tox/py27/bin/python -V` prints out `Python 2.7.6` which makes me think the `basepython` keyword is not respected...